# Eating with non jews

Tags: contemporary-halacha

Is there any prohibition in jews and non jews sitting at the same table and eating kosher food together at a jewish? wedding?  Thank you.

Comment: Why would there be?

Comment: related https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/71744/eating-with-gentiles

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of the post @rosends linked to. Am I missing something?

Comment: I wasn't sure if the wedding angle differentiated.

Comment: You should differentiate between a Jewish wedding or at the house of a Jew and the celebration of a nonJew. The two cases are different. You should make it clear in the question who is having the celebration.

Answer (score 2):

The following question was asked at “din.org.il”:

> האם יש איסור באכילה עם גוי על שולחן אחד? ואם כן האם יש נ”מ בין קביעת
>   סעודה על לחם לשאר אוכלים?
>
> Is there any prohibition of eating with a non-Jew at the same table?
>   If so, is there any difference between a meal with bread or with other
>   foods?

The following answer was given by the רבני בית ההוראה:

> יש מהפוסקים שכתבו שאסור לאכול בכל מקרה עם גוי על שולחן אחד, ואפילו אם
>   מזמין את הגוי לביתו אסור לאכול ולשתות עמו יין או יי”ש, אלא אם כן רוב
>   המסובים הינם ישראלים, (אבל אם הם רק שניים הוא והגוי אסור לאכול או
>   לשתות ביחד, ואפילו במסעדה שכל אחד משלם על מאכליו ושתייתו גם כן אסור,
>   ובכלל איסור זה הוא אכילת כל מאכל שיש בו משום בישול עכו”ם או דבר שיש בו
>   משום יין עכו”ם, וכן בכלל זה הוא שתיית שכר או יי”ש).
>
> There are authorities that prohibit eating with  a non-Jew at the same
>   table and even if the Jew invites the non-Jew to his house he may not
>   eat and drink wine or spirits with him unless the majority of the
>   people eating are Jewish. (But if there are just the two of them the
>   Jew may not eat together with the non-Jew. And even in a restaurant
>   where each pays separately for their meal, it is still forbidden.
>   Included in this prohibition is consumption of food that is forbidden
>   under “bishul akum” or wine of akum or drinking beer or spirits.)
>
> כאשר מדובר על מסיבה שהגוי עורך או שהיהודי עורך ומזמין גוי אסור לכל
>   הדיעות לאכול עם הגוי על שולחן אחד, אולם אם ישובים כל אחד בשולחן נפרד,
>   אם המסיבה היא בבית הגוי אסור לאכול ולשתות שם, אך אם המסיבה בבית היהודי
>   מותר אם אין אוכלים  בשולחן אחד וכן אם הרוב יהודים.
>
> When we speak of a feast which either the non-Jew or the Jew arranges,
>   it is forbidden according to all opinions to eat with the non-Jew at
>   the same table. If each one sits at his own separate table, then if
>   the feast is in the house of the non-Jew, the Jew cannot eat there but
>   if it is in the Jew's house, it is allowed as long as they do not eat
>   at one table [and the majority of people are Jews].
>
> דברים אלו שנאסרו, הם כדי שהיהודי לא יבוא ח”ו לידי קירוב מדי לגוי,
>   ויבוא בסופו של דבר להתחתן עם בנות הנכרים, וכן אשה שמא תתחתן עם הנכרי.
>
> These prohibited actions are in order that the Jew should not get into
>   a close relationship with the non-Jew which eventually might lead to
>   intermarriage.
>
> במקום שיש חשש שהדבר יביא לידי איבה מותר לשבת ולאכל יחד עם הגוי על
>   שולחן אחד, וכמובן רק מאכלים כשרים.
>
> In a situation where refusal to eat together could lead to ongoing
>   animosity, it is permitted to sit and eat with a non-Jew at one table
>   – obviously only kosher foods.

There is an impressive list of sources.

From the above, for a Jewish wedding, we can assume that the majority of participants are Jewish. Then the non-Jew must eat at a separate table. Where this would lead to  איבה which I understand to be ongoing animosity, enmity or hatred, the Jew could eat at the same table as the non-Jew.

Comment: "Where this would lead to איבה" that's the vast vast vast majority of modern cases

Comment: I'm very interested that you are so emphatic about the possibility of איבה. Please tell how you know.

Comment: Social awareness?

Comment: Sources? Links?

Comment: https://din.org.il/2012/01/04/%D7%90%D7%9B%D7%99%D7%9C%D7%94-%D7%A2%D7%9D-%D7%A0%D7%9B%D7%A8%D7%99-%D7%A2%D7%9C-%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%97%D7%9F-%D7%90%D7%97%D7%93/

Comment: You write that there is an impressive list of sources. But it only brings one source. And it is very unimpressive. The prohibition is clearly only by weddings and similar parties.